# Linux - Difference between migrations and switches?

Tags: linux, multithreading, linux-kernel, scheduler

By looking at the scheduling stats in `/proc/<PID>/sched`, you can get an output like this:

```
[horro@system ~]$ cat /proc/1/sched
systemd (1, #threads: 1)
-------------------------------------------------------------------
se.exec_start                                :    2499611106.982616
se.vruntime                                  :          7952.917943
se.sum_exec_runtime                          :         58651.279127
se.nr_migrations                             :                53355
nr_switches                                  :               169561
nr_voluntary_switches                        :               168185
nr_involuntary_switches                      :                 1376
se.load.weight                               :              1048576
se.avg.load_sum                              :               343837
se.avg.util_sum                              :               338827
se.avg.load_avg                              :                    7
se.avg.util_avg                              :                    7
se.avg.last_update_time                      :     2499611106982616
policy                                       :                    0
prio                                         :                  120
clock-delta                                  :                  180
mm->numa_scan_seq                            :                    1
numa_pages_migrated                          :                  296
numa_preferred_nid                           :                    0
total_numa_faults                            :                   34
current_node=0, numa_group_id=0
numa_faults node=0 task_private=0 task_shared=23 group_private=0 group_shared=0
numa_faults node=1 task_private=0 task_shared=0 group_private=0 group_shared=0
numa_faults node=2 task_private=0 task_shared=0 group_private=0 group_shared=0
numa_faults node=3 task_private=0 task_shared=11 group_private=0 group_shared=0
numa_faults node=4 task_private=0 task_shared=0 group_private=0 group_shared=0
numa_faults node=5 task_private=0 task_shared=0 group_private=0 group_shared=0
numa_faults node=6 task_private=0 task_shared=0 group_private=0 group_shared=0
numa_faults node=7 task_private=0 task_shared=0 group_private=0 group_shared=0
```

I have been trying to figure out what are the differences between migrations and switches, some responses [here](http://blog.tanelpoder.com/2013/02/21/peeking-into-linux-kernel-land-using-proc-filesystem-for-quickndirty-troubleshooting/) and [here](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/can-someone-explain-the-output-of-proc-pid-sched-4175412750/). Summarizing these responses:

- `nr_switches`: number of context switches.
- `nr_voluntary_switches`: number of voluntary switches, i.e. the thread blocked and hence another thread is picked up.
- `nr_involuntary_switches`: the scheduler kicked the thread out as there is another hungry thread is ready to run.

Therefore, what are the `migrations`? Are these concepts related or not? Migrations are among cores and switches within a core?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Migration is when a thread, usually after a context switch, get scheduled on a different CPU than it was scheduled before.

**EDIT 1**:

Here is more info on Wikipedia about the migration: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_migration

Here is the kernel code increasing the counter:
https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/kernel/sched/core.c#L1175

```
if (task_cpu(p) != new_cpu) {
    ...
    p->se.nr_migrations++;
```

**EDIT 2**:

A thread can migrate to another CPU in the following cases:

1. During `exec()`
2. During `fork()`
3. During thread wake-up.
4. If thread affinity mask has changed.
5. When the current CPU is getting offline.

For more info please have a look at functions `set_task_cpu()`, `move_queued_task()`, `migrate_tasks()` in the same source file: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/kernel/sched/core.c

The policies scheduler follows are described in `select_task_rq()`, which depend on the class of scheduler you are using. The basic version of the policier:

```
if (p->nr_cpus_allowed > 1)
    cpu = p->sched_class->select_task_rq(p, cpu, sd_flags, wake_flags);
else
    cpu = cpumask_any(&p->cpus_allowed);
```

Source: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/kernel/sched/core.c#L1534

So in order to *avoid* the migration, set the CPU affinity mask for your threads using `sched_setaffinity(2)` system call or corresponding POSIX API `pthread_setaffinity_np(3)`.

Here is the definition of select_task_rq() for the Completely Fair Scheduler:
https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/kernel/sched/fair.c#L5860

The logic is quite complicated, but basically, we either select sibling idle CPU or find a least busy new one.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: You say 'usually', so what policies does the scheduler follow to migrate to another core? Do you have any sources that can confirm that?

Comment: It depends on scheduler, priorities, affinities etc. Basically, if there is no CPU affinity and the previous CPU is being busy with another task, the thread get scheduled on another CPU. I also updated the answer with some links.

Comment: @horro, having experimented with manual control of thread-core affinity, I concluded that there's no point, the policies are too deeply involved. There's so much that has to be taken into account, and it's different for every single computer. One example, on a dual CPU machine you might consider which CPU has most of the thread's data (there's no point overloading the QPI bus). That in itself is a complicated question; successive memory pages can be interleaved between the CPUs, or not (it's a BIOS setting on some machines). The OS knows all this and more. I fear to pry too deep...

Comment: @AndriyBerestovskyy Could you please describe in a few words what performance issues cpu migration can cause? From my understanding now this seems the same to me as that some thread de-scheduled from some CPU and later on is scheduled to a different one is similar to if it would scheduled to the same one, no? I mean how affinity helps?

Comment: @St.Antario in a few words: migration causes more cache misses (modern CPUs have at least instruction, data and TLB caches), more branch predictor misses, etc. Pretty sure there is something else, but that is what came to my mind at the moment ;)

Comment: @AndriyBerestovskyy Thanks much for the reply! But I'd like to ask you one more clarification. Does it mean that modern CPUs do not allow accessing their L1 cache directly, but only higher level caches? So OS cannot swap the L1 caches when context switching. Is that correct?

Comment: @St.Antario usually L1 cache is "private". That is why [L1 cache is few times faster than L2](https://www.slideshare.net/AndriyBerestovskyy/xeon-what-new-intel-xeon-processors-with-many-integrated-core-mic-architecture/19). There are cache coherency protocols, but usually data go through the point of coherency (i.e. a higher level cache). The TLB cache and branch predictor history go to the bin AFAIK. Have a look at my [The Spectre of Meltdowns](https://www.slideshare.net/AndriyBerestovskyy/the-spectre-of-meltdowns) presentation for the basics of cache and branch predictor.

Comment: Informative answer.  Tho, in my case I see se.nr_migrations=6 for my single threaded process that has started with taskset to an isolated core.  Any idea how it could be "migrated"?  So far I haven't seen it has actually been running on a different core (tho, I don't have a script or anything to monitor).  Thanks!

Comment: @HCSF ask a new question, add more info (taskset command line arguments, how you do the core isolation etc) and I will have a look. Frankly, 6 migrations it is not that much...

Comment: @AndriyBerestovskyy I just posted a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52736873/understanding-scheduling-and-proc-pid-sched).  Your insight is highly appreciated!