# Understanding Scheduling and /proc/[pid]/sched

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, scheduler, scheduling

I have a single threaded application that is (spinning and) pinned to a core with taskset and CPU isolation (i.e. isolcpus=12-23 nohz_full=21,22,23 rcu_nocbs=12-23; I have 2 CPUs, and 12 core each -- Skylake):

```
exec taskset -c 22 setuidgid myuser envdir ./env -c = /opt/bin/UtilityServer > /tmp/logs/utility-server.log
```

For some reason, after running few hours, I checked the stats:

```
UtilityServer (1934, #threads: 1)
-------------------------------------------------------------------
se.exec_start                                :      78998944.120048
se.vruntime                                  :      78337609.962134
se.sum_exec_runtime                          :      78337613.040860
se.nr_migrations                             :                    6
nr_switches                                  :                   41
nr_voluntary_switches                        :                   31
nr_involuntary_switches                      :                   10
se.load.weight                               :                 1024
policy                                       :                    0
prio                                         :                  120
clock-delta                                  :                   13
mm->numa_scan_seq                            :                  925
numa_migrations, 0
numa_faults_memory, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1
numa_faults_memory, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1
numa_faults_memory, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0
numa_faults_memory, 1, 1, 0, 1, 9
```

Questions:

1. How can I stop the switching and migration (i.e. `se.nr_migrations`, `nr_switches`, `nr_voluntary_switches`, `nr_involuntary_switches` are zero)?  Given that my application really wants to use the whole core.
2. Why did the kernel try to migrate?  Given that I have already isolated the core and only assigned one single threaded application there.
3. `nr_voluntary_switches` tracked the # of times that my application voluntarily gave up the core?  If yes, under what situation that my application would give up the core?  My application did do some non blocking disk I/O (i.e. `fwrite_unlocked()`, etc) but zero networking stuffs.
4. Under what situation my application would be forced to switch?  I see that `nr_involuntary_switches` = 10, it means my application was forced to switch 10 times?
5. What do the numbers after `numa_faults_memory` entries mean?

I am on 3.10.0-862.2.3.el7.x86_64 if it matters.

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, there are too many questions and no code ;) Have a look at the `fwrite_unlock()`. Usually, it ends with a `write(2)` syscall and this is the source of context switches... For more info look into the [kernel `__schedule()`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/kernel/sched/core.c#L3344). That is the place where the context switch counters get increased.

Comment: Haha, I just tried to ask all questions at once instead of adding one by one later; otherwise, would upset people trying to answer.  The code is a bit long -- few thousand lines.  I actually call `__fsetlocking()` to advise glibc not to lock unless caller asks for.  And then I call `fprintf()` 3 times + `fflush()` every ~5 sec and `vfprintf()`, `fwrite_unlocked()`, and `fflush_unlocked()` every few hours.  I will take a look at the sources of all those functions in glibc.  Thanks for the pointers :)

Comment: Actually, those switches should have nothing to do with all those writes because I have cronjobs to capture at the stats at 9AM, 3:15PM, 9PM, and 2:45AM.  Those switch counts didn't increase for few days.  But you have inspired me -- context switch due to I/O access.  I believe those are related to my application reading the configuration file at startup.  So #3 is kind of answered.   Thanks!